# Complex numbers $p$ without $q$, $r$ such that $p+q+r=1$ and $|p|=|q|=|r|$

Tags: complex-numbers

> Describe all complex numbers $p$ such that there do not exist complex numbers $q$, $r$ satisfying $|p|=|q|=|r|$ and $p+q+r=1$.

I was not sure how to tackle this question. I tried writing $p=a+bi$, $q=c+di$, $r=e+fi$ and hopefully turning the complexes to reals, but I didn't get anywhere with this. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: The title does not match the question.

Comment: Thank you, the statement in the question is correct, and the title was wrong.

Comment: Geometric hint: $\frac{1}{3}(p+q+r)$ is the centroid of triangle $pqr$ inscribed in circle $z=|p|$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick intuition: $|q+r|$ must be big enough to "reach" from $p$ to $1$.  If $|p|$ is very small (e.g. if $p$ is a positive real $<\frac 1 3$), then there's no way $p+q+r$ could add up to 1.

More formally:

Because of the triangle inequality, if $p + q + r = 1$ the distance from $1$ to $p$ must be less than or equal to $|q| + |r|$:
$$|1-p| = |q+r| \leq |q| + |r| = 2|p|$$
Substitute $p = a + bi$, and square both sides:
$$(1-a)^2+b^2 \leq 4(a^2 + b^2)$$
$$1 \leq 3a^2 + 2a + 3b^2 = 3(a^2 + \frac{2}{3}a) + 3b^2$$
Completing the square:
$$ 1 + \frac{1}{3} \leq 3(a + \frac{1}{3})^2 + 3b^2$$
$$ \frac{4}{9} \leq (a + \frac{1}{3})^2 + b^2$$
So, if $p$ lies on the circumference or outside the circle defined by the above equation (radius $\frac{2}{3}$, centered around $-\frac{1}{3}$), then $q$, $r$ s.t. $p + q + r = 1$ and $|p|=|q|=|r|$ *can* be found.

If $p$ lies *inside* the circle of radius $\frac{2}{3}$, centered around $-\frac{1}{3}$, then no such $q,r$ exist.